# Login to WinApi C# using Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs

I get this error when I send Post. Do you know what I have to do? Login to WinApi C#

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56305/Token. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64757' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

My code

```
//linki
    $scope.addLink = "http://localhost:56305/Token";

    $scope.addData = function () {
        if ($scope.password != "" && $scope.email) {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: $scope.addLink,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                headers: {'X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest'},
                data: { grant_type: 'password', username: $scope.email, Password: $scope.password }
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                $scope.stateHideError = true;
                $scope.stateHideSuccess = false;
                Authorization.go('carInsurance');
            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.stateHideError = false;
                $scope.stateHideSuccess = true;
                $scope.error = "Wystąpił błąd - Problem z wysłaniem parametrów";
            });
        }
        else {
            $scope.stateHideError = false;
            $scope.stateHideSuccess = true;
            $scope.error = "Wystąpił błąd - nie podałeś wszystkich wymaganych wartości.";
        }
    };
```

PtrScn
[image]

I would like send something like this

[image]

I added this to WinApi C#

```
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

and now I have this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56305/Token. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample article, how to enable CORS
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Your server rejects requests from your js application,because your js is loaded from different URL